# angular.js Is it possible to load third party content via a template?

Tags: angularjs, templates, http-headers, httprequest

I am creating a site using angular but I have a requirement to embed third party content into a template, or more precisely into a page that would normally be a template except I am grabbing the content from a third party. In this case it is a form coming from Podio.

Podio allows you to embed content and usually provides a script like this.

```
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->
<script src="https://podio.com/webforms/nnnnnnn/nnnnnnn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _podioWebForm.render("nnnnnn")
</script>
<!-- END Podio web form -->
```

However, this embeds an iFrame which I don't want, neither does it work, because (I think) Angular does not parse script tags when it loads a template. (If anyone can confirm this I'd be interested although it's not the subject of the question).

I just want the pure form which I can get if I visit:

```
https://podio.com/webforms/nnnnnnn/nnnnnnn/.
```

I have tried to substitute the URL of the template with this, and of course a cross-domain http request is started, which nearly works except it does not allow cross origin requests without the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header`.

I read that it is possible using

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

which I insert into my `.config` but it does not seem to work. My question is basically, can this cross domain call work, and if so how do I make it work?

Comment: First of all, did you remember to do `$rootScope.$apply()` **after** your third party content get rendered?
$apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is basically, can this cross domain call work, and if so
>   how do I make it work?

That depends. Cross domain calls will only work if the server allows them, it is not enough for the client to make the correct request if the server is not configured to allow it. Does the server in question support it? If not you will need to add it (if you have control over the server), search for Access-Control-Allow-Origin and server here on SO, there are lots of guides on how to do it.

But I assume you don't have control over the server so you might be in trouble. You could try getting it with jsonp but the same thing goes there, the server needs to support it.

The last option is to proxy via a server you do control. Request the template from your server and let your server read it from the target server and then serve it forward.

Comment: Podio allows you to specify a domain to give it permission to make this cross domain request. However that's not really my question. I am asking how to configure Angular to make this request as if it was loading a template.